# How can I set the dimensions in an image CDN using CSS?

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation, pagespeed

**CSS**

```
img {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://images.xxxxxxx.co.uk/content/icon.png" alt="xxxxxxxxx" />
```

I get the same error in page speed

**Specify image dimensions**
The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes.

```
http://images.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk/content/icon.png (Dimensions: 67 x 75)
```

there is a solution using .htaccess or jQuery ?

Comment: Have you tried using a class on your `img`?

Comment: PageSpeed specifically wants a height / width against the image. I've run into this in the past. The crawler doesn't care about the CSS so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with adding them to the image tag:

```
<img src="http://images.xxxxxxx.co.uk/content/icon.png" width="67px" height="75px" alt="xxxxxxxxx" />
```

You can't do what you want with JQuery because Search engines / PageSpeed won't render javascript and in turn it won't do anything for crawlers.

This is the same for CSS, the crawler (which is the purpose of the optimisation through PageSpeed) won't run through the CSS so if it's for SEO, CSS won't do either.

Comment: He asked for a `css` solution.

Comment: Just because someone asks for a solution in a specific way, it doesn't mean they should do it that way. This is the correct way to specify the image width / height in an image for PageSpeed purposes.

Comment: @webnoob *What's wrong with adding them to the image tag* ← this made me remove the downvote.

Comment: I noticed I phrased it incorrectly after pressing post ;)